# Start ratpack.groovy from Java

Tags: groovy, ratpack

I´m trying to use ratpack groovy framework from Java, but I cannot find a way to init from Java.

Any idea how to start up a ratpack.groovy script from Java?

This is my ratpack script

```
 ratpack {
def tokens=[:]
serverConfig {
    port 9000
}
handlers {
    get("identity/:token") {
        def token= pathTokens["token"]
        render tokens[token]
    }
}
}
```

Regards.

Comment: You want to use `RatpackServer.of`, an example of this is [here](http://asaf.github.io/blog/2015/02/15/ratpack_hello_world/)

Comment: Thanks but what I´m looking is how to use a ratpack.groovy from Java. I dont want to code in Java, it´s much more verbose

Comment: Ah ok I missed that nuance, I would suggest then still using `RatpackServer` to initialize the server and then use a `GroovyChainAction` to define your handlers.

Comment: Do you know any place where I can take a look a code example to do that?, thank!

Comment: Probably the most concise example is in the [javadoc](https://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/groovy/handling/GroovyChainAction.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [GroovyRatpackMain](https://github.com/ratpack/ratpack/blob/master/ratpack-groovy/src/main/java/ratpack/groovy/GroovyRatpackMain.java), you can start a Groovy app from Java like this:

```
import ratpack.server.RatpackServer;

RatpackServer.start(Groovy.Script.appWithArgs(args));
```

If you need to use a non-default script file or perform other customization, [Groovy.Script](https://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/groovy/Groovy.Script.html) has methods to support that.